# Docker and GO runtime

Tags: docker, go, runtime

First of all, I would call myself a C/C++ programmer. I do not have years of experiences on Docker or Go. Thus, my questions might be silly although I am writing this after putting my best efforts on Google search.

My question is whether Docker requires GO runtime when it runs or not. I have read that docker itself is written in GO. I could see that a GO compiler is necessary to build a docker binary. Say, I build a docker binary on a build machine and remotely distribute. For example, I am building a .deb docker package on machine A, and distributes it for the users' machine B, C, D, E, and F. Do B, C, D, E, and F ever need GO installed to run my docker?

If docker were written in C/C++ and linked with DLL(s), I would know the answer. If docker were written in C/C++ and statically linked, I would also know the answer. However, I do not know so well how a GO program runs and what particularly docker requires.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is whether Docker requires GO runtime when it runs or not. I have read that docker itself is written in GO.

No, it does not. And Go produces [statically linked binaries](https://www.reddit.com/r/golang/comments/53nl4b/why_all_go_binaries_are_staticallylinked/), so it does not require any dll dependencies on runtime.

For a more detailed list of actual Docker dependencies, see "[Install Docker CE from binaries](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/linux/docker-ce/binaries/#prerequisites)".